# Checkboxlist latest checked/unchecked item

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist, checked, unchecked

I have a need to get the latest checked or unchecked item from a checkboxlist. Basically I need to detect any change in the list and perform some action on that.

I found the solution for latest checked item but couldn't find one for the latest unchecked item.

Is it possible to do that with the checkboxlist or I will have to go with another control?

Comment: Oh. BTW, I load the checkboxlist control dynamically. And there are dynamic number of them. And one change in one checkboxlist will impact the selection for other checkboxlist(s). Is the checkboxlist the right choice for this design requirment ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old...but might as well throw an answer out there.  One option is to create a datatable for the selected items in the CheckBoxList(CBL) on databind, scrub that table against the selected items in the CBL, and find the difference.